# How to bind an array to multiple dropdown lists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My model contains an array of items:

```
public class MyModel
{
     public IEnumerable<ListItem> AllItems { get; set; }
     public string[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

I understand it's simple enough to create a single multi-select drop-down list and render it with Razor, but my list of items is pretty long and multi-selecting does not make for a good UI experience (too easy to lose selections).

I would rather have separate dropdown for each item. This is easy enough to manage with HTML / JS, but I am wondering what my element IDs should be for the model binding in MVC to work on submit.

Thanks!

**Update**

What I want to end up with is the something similar to this HTML, where I would have one list per selected item, with ability to add a new item or remove existing one:

```
<select>
    <option value="1" selected>blah</option>
    ...
    <option value="15">blah</option>
    ...
    <option value="xx">[ remove this item ]</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option value="1">blah</option>
    ...
    <option value="15" selected>blah</option>
    ...
    <option value="xx">[ remove this item ]</option>
</select>

<button>Add another</button>
```

I hope that clears my question up a bit.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "A separate dropdown for each item".  If you have a very long list, that means a lot of drop downs.  Why not just use checkboxes at that point?  The purpose of a dropdown is to condense many items into a single space.  If you only have one item, then a dropdown is pointless.

Comment: @MystereMan You misunderstand: the full list of items is rather long (100+). The selected item count is comparatively small (<20). I want to display a separate dropdown containing `AllItems` for each item in `SelectedItems` array.

Comment: I'm still not getting it.  You want a dropdown containing AllItems for each item in SelectedItems array?  The way you're phrasing this makes no sense to me.  Can you maybe take a screenshot of what you're trying to do and edit your question to include it?

Comment: Are you effectively wanting to mimic the behaviour Excel has when you bind a column of data to a list of values? Where the cell displays the selected value and allows you to drop down a list to choose from?

Comment: In the end, I reimagined my UI approach and went with a scrolling list of checkboxes, managed with knockout.js.